# How to create shortcuts from a list of files in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

**Backstory**

I originally had access to a shared Google Drive folder `TIF_Images` with images `Image01.tif` to `Image1000.tif`. I spent many hours organizing the images by making shortcuts and putting those into various folders of shortcuts, for example `Pictures_of_trees`, `Pictures_of_dogs`.

Due to institutional archiving policies, I have now lost read access to `TIF_Images` but gained access to `JPG_Images`, which contains lower res .jpg copies of all the same images. In order to avoid organizing all the images again by hand, I wanted to use a Google Drive script to look at each folder of .tif shortcuts and remake the shortcuts with the new .jpg versions of the images.

**What I am trying to do**

Given a folder in a shared Google Drive with shortcuts to `Image01.tif` and `Image02.tif`, the code should create new shortcuts to `Image01.jpg` and `Image02.jpg` in the same folder. Here is an [example](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RFrTEq-l6MCZ3GHhmbM_bCrNs4iIzd01?usp=sharing) of the folder structure I am starting out with. The desired code should create two new shortcuts in the `Pictures_of_trees` folder: shortcuts to `Image01.jpg` and `Image02.jpg`.

I think I have the first part figured out on getting all .jpg versions of the .tif images in a given folder but I'm having trouble actually making the shortcuts from that list of .jpg's. This is my first time using Google scripts or Javascript so I'm sure this code is ugly and incorrect. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function myFunction() {
 // Get the folder with .jpg's
 var jpgFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of JPG_Images folder");
 
 // Get the target new shortcuts folder, which is just the old folder with shortcuts in it
 var origFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of a shortcut folder like Pictures_of_trees");
 var targetFolder = origFolder;


 // Get all the .tif shortcuts out of the original shortcuts
 var origFiles = origFolder.getFiles();
 while(origFiles.hasNext()){
   var origFile = origFiles.next();
   var origName = origFile.getName()
   // Swap out tif for jpg in the name
   const regex = new RegExp("(?:tif)", 'gm')
   var str = origName;
   const subst = `jpg`;
   
   // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
   var newName = str.replace(regex, subst);
   console.log("newName", newName);
   
   // Get the ID for the jpg image
   var newFiles = jpgFolder.getFilesByName(newName)
   // Probably messing up with the Class Fileiterator here. I need a Class File but not sure how to get that

   // This should create a new shortcut in the folder linking back to the .jpg version of the image but the code breaks here. 


   newFiles.createShortcut(targetFolder)

 }
 

}
```

Note that in the code above, `createShortcut()` should reference this [Google function `createShortcut()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createshortcuttargetid).

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to generous help from @Tanaike and @Twilight (see comments), I have been able to get [Tanaike's](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/05/28/creating-shortcut-on-google-drive-using-google-apps-script/) `createShortcut` function to work. I'll post my own answer with the updated code.

Comment: First, I apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. About your error of `Drive id not defined` in my script, I apologize for my poor English skill. I think that the reason for this is due to that you have never enabled Drive API. Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services, and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) About your showing script, I couldn't understand your expected result.

Comment: @Tanaike, I double checked that Drive API is enabled and I think it is although I now get a slightly different error (updated above). I also updated my question to hopefully make it clearer what expected result of the code should be. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested [my script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/05/28/creating-shortcut-on-google-drive-using-google-apps-script/), a new shortcut can be created without errors. I think that the reason for the no error is due to my poor skill. I apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Did you correctly copy and paste my script? I'm worried about it.

Comment: @Tanaike, no worries, the problem is likely on my side. I am very new to coding in Google Scripts. I copy and pasted your code again, and tried it on this [example file structure](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RFrTEq-l6MCZ3GHhmbM_bCrNs4iIzd01?usp=sharing) that I created. Still getting same error at the line `const shortcut = Drive.Files.insert(resource);`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation of `Bad Request`. I apologize for this. In your situation, do you have permission for the file or folder you want to use? If you have no permission, the script cannot be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: I do have permissions so maybe I am doing something else wrong. I'll keep working on it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For example, your target file is put into the shared drive?

Comment: The reason why you are getting the error above is because you are running the `createShortcut` function instead of the `main` function, this is from the provided code of @Tanaike. The createShortcut function is looking for 3 input parameters. As for your own code, please specify/clarify your desired output/goal, from your sample (toy example link) it already contains both .tiff and .jpeg files.

Comment: @Twilight, have updated the question to hopefully clarify my desired output and I have included my call of Tanaike's code

Comment: I am able to replicate your error when running the `createShortcut function`, this is because you cannot run it alone without the input parameters. His code is working on my end as well: https://imgur.com/GXa7uwt. .

Comment: @Mammoth About your updated question of `EDIT: Thanks to generous help from @Tanaike and @Twilight (see comments), I have been able to get Tanaike's createShortcut function to work. Now, I just need to figure out how to get the ID's from a string of file names and pass them to the createShortcut function.`, your initial question was resolved, and do you have new question? Or do you want to change your question? Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: In addition to @Tanaike's comment,  I am confused about your new question as you can already use his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many helpful comments, I arrived at this ugly but workable code. It works for the [toy example](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RFrTEq-l6MCZ3GHhmbM_bCrNs4iIzd01?usp=sharing) folder I posted in my question and also my real data, which is more complicated.

**NOTE:**
You have to have `const shortcut = Drive.Files.insert(resource, undefined, {supportsAllDrives: true});` in the `createShortcut` function [if your shortcuts are on a Shared Drive](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/bH-kn9UW_cg).

```
function createShortcut(targetId, name, folderId) {
  const resource = {
    shortcutDetails: { targetId: targetId },
    title: name,
    mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
  };
  if (folderId) resource.parents = [{ id: folderId }];
  const shortcut = Drive.Files.insert(resource, undefined, {supportsAllDrives: true});
  return shortcut.id;
}





function myFunction() {
 // Get the folder with .jpg's
 var jpgFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1wugRsnTKptJzJi4_0jnreJJyBUrQ0L9I"); //ID of JPG_Images folder
 
 // Get the folder where the shortcuts will go. This is the original folder with shortcuts in it
 var origFolderID = "1su9LmBDPxt480NFeOEHUCEfRQY0hoWp3"; //ID of a shortcuts folder like Pictures_of_trees
 var origFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(origFolderID); 
 var targetFolderID = origFolderID;


 // Get all the .tif shortcuts out of the original shortcuts
 var origFiles = origFolder.getFiles();
 while(origFiles.hasNext()){
   var origFile = origFiles.next();
   var origName = origFile.getName()
   // Swap out tif for jpg in the name
   const regex = new RegExp("(?:tiff)", 'gm')
   var str = origName;
   const subst = `jpeg`;
   
   
   var newName = str.replace(regex, subst);
   console.log("newName", newName);
   
   // Get the ID for the jpg image
   var newFiles = jpgFolder.getFilesByName(newName);
  

   while (newFiles.hasNext()) {
     var file = newFiles.next();
     var newID = file.getId();
     //console.log("newID", newID);
   }

   
      const targetId = newID; // Please set the ID of target file. 
      //console.log("targetId", targetId);
      if (typeof newID === 'undefined'){
     continue;
   }
      
      const shortcutName = newName; // Set the shortcut name. This is just the file name
      //console.log("shortcutName", shortcutName);

      const folderId = targetFolderID; // Set the folder ID where the created shortcut will go. 
      //console.log("folderId", folderId);

      const id = createShortcut(targetId, shortcutName, folderId);
      console.log("shortcut ID", id);
   


 }
 

}
```

Comment: _defensively coding around them_: use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).